# Can't reach service function outside of constructor

Tags: angular, typescript

I've looked at other solutions because there were questions similar to mine but I couldn't find an answer. I'm not sure what to do here, I've tried multiple different ways. I'm pretty new to Angular.

**ERROR:**

books-search.component.ts:13 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'testService' of undefined

**UPDATE:**

I believed I could test the method there but was wrong. I ended up with a new error after moving the method call.

**NEW ERROR:**

compiler.js:19550 Uncaught Error: Provider parse errors:
Cannot instantiate cyclic dependency! BooksService ("[ERROR ->]"): in NgModule AppModule in ./AppModule@-1:-1

**UPDATE:**

Fixed the error, thanks.

**books-search.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import { BooksService } from '../services/books.service';
declare var jquery:any;
declare var $ :any;
@Component({
  selector: 'app-books-search',
  templateUrl: './books-search.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./books-search.component.css']
})
export class BooksSearchComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private service:BooksService){};
  ngOnInit(){
//moved here after second edit
  this.service.testService();}
  searchBook(bookTitle:string){
    var searchTerm = '';
    var books = [];
    //initial api url
    var googleAPI = "https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=";
    //grabbing our search term
    searchTerm = bookTitle;
    //replacing spaces with +
    searchTerm.toString();
    searchTerm = searchTerm.replace(/ /g,"+");
    //adding our searchterm to our api
    googleAPI += searchTerm;
    // gets a json object from google books api
    $.getJSON(googleAPI, function(response){
      this.service.testService();
    });
  }
}
```

**books.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class BooksService {
  constructor(private service: BooksService){}
  public books = [];
  testService(){
    console.log('service test success!');
  }
  setData(data){
    this.books = data;
    console.log('data set : ' + this.books);
  }
  getData(){
    return this.books;
  }
}
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BooksService } from './services/books.service';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { BooksSearchResultComponent } from './books-search-result/books-search-result.component';
import { BookshelfComponent } from './bookshelf/bookshelf.component';
import { BooksSearchComponent } from './books-search/books-search.component';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    BooksSearchResultComponent,
    BookshelfComponent,
    BooksSearchComponent
  ],
  imports: [BrowserModule],
  providers: [BooksService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: Replace your `function`  with `arrow function`.
`$.getJSON(googleAPI, (response) => this.service.testService());`

Comment: Why is your `this.service.testService()` out of ngOnInit function block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call testService() inside ngOnInit()

```
ngOnInit(){
this.service.testService();
}
```

// for second error remove injecting the service itself

```
@Injectable()
export class BooksService {
constructor(){}
}
```

Comment: @KoalaCode if this answer solves your problem, could you accept it as an answer

Comment: it did solve the answer but a new error popped up after that one. Sorry I've been working on this for hours, I'm pretty new to Angular.

Comment: if the new error doesn't relate to this issue, kindly select the 'correct' mark

Comment: It solved the initial answer so I accepted the answer. Any idea to the following error?

Comment: remove the injection of the service inside service itself.

Comment: @KoalaCode circular dependency means, each components/services depends on each other(A<->B). you need to refactor your code to avoid such type of dependencies. need to remove `private service: BooksService` from your BooksService

Comment: @KoalaCode remove the '(private service: BooksService' from BooksService constructor

Comment: Dang, yeah that fixed it. I got so frustrated with code I just keep placing things around to try and fix it earlier.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have `this.service.testService();` inside a method. It's just floating out there by itself inside the body of the class definition. Did you intend to put it inside your `ngOnInit()' function, instead of closing that off with empty braces?

Answer (score 1):

You are injecting BooksService in it's own constructor
try to remove it and it should work.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class BooksService {
    constructor(){}
    //... the rest of the class
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in service itself

```
@Injectable()
export class BooksService {
  constructor(private service: BooksService){}
```

you are injecting BookService in its own constructor, remove it and then check

```
@Injectable()
export class BooksService {
  constructor(){}
```